# Trying to install new libraries on Spyder (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I am new to python and I am having trouble downloading some new libraries that don't appear to be pre-installed.  The names of them are rasterio and retrying.  I continuously get an invalid syntax error, and I have tried using some different suggestions found online.

pip install rasterio

Above is the way I was attempting to do it, and I also tried without the pip in there, but neither option worked.  I am new enough to the language that troubleshooting is very difficult.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error? Where are you executing the commands?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Spyder IDE with Anaconda. So, to install rasterio package you can open anaconda prompt and type:

`conda install -c conda-forge rasterio`

For further information about package installation check out this [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/).
Also, to install any conda packages just google it once, you will find instructions to install it mostly in anaconda's official site.

Edit:
Please remove the rasterio package once. And install it again, see if works. If it doesn't work create a new environment like: `conda create --name myenv`. Then install rasterio again.

If this still doesn't work, try to install rasterio from [here](https://anaconda.org/ioos/rasterio) like `conda install -c ioos rasterio`.

Comment: I am still getting a syntax error with the ^ pointing to the last 'L' in "install"

Comment: I ran that code in the anaconda prompt, and then tried to import into my Spyder project but it didn't work

Comment: @oerik100 could you post the screenshots of how you entered the commands?

Comment: I got the rasterio package to install, but now I am getting an error on the import.

Comment: @oerik100 see my edited answer. Maybe it will help.

Comment: @oerik100 _tried to import into my Spyder project but it didn't work_ It might be best to test things using a simple Python file first, Spyder just adds another layer of complexity and potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to install rasterio, using anaconda you have the **documentation here**: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/rasterio

If you are on windows installing rasterio using pip install can be difficult since it requires binary wheels, but here is the **tutorial**: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I advise you to use linux since it is much easier to install packages, you can either install a dual boot or a virtual box.

Comment: I tried using those but I still wasn't able to import rasterio into my current project. @DPM

Comment: Hmm okay, I've had that type of problem before with another package and the onoly solution for me was to install linux and only code there. Can tell you that it is worth it.